# How to serve tensorflow model using flask+uwsgi?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, uwsgi

I have a trained model which I want to use to predict some data and serve it using flask + uwsgi. Everything works fine but when I hit the server sometimes it throws an error:

```
File "api.py", line 150, in get_data
   im = sess.run(image_tf)
`ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'DecodeJpeg_2:0' shape=(?, ?, 3) dtype=uint8> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. 
      (Tensor Tensor("DecodeJpeg_2:0", shape=(?, ?, 3), dtype=uint8) 
       is not an element of this graph.)`
```

Few requests work correctly but fe throws the above error. I figured out it has something to do with the tensorflow session but I'm not able to figure out how can I use it in flask efficiently. Below is the snippet:

```
config = my_config_pb2.MyConfig()
with tf.gfile.FastGFile('myconfig.pbtxt', 'r') as f:
  text_format.Merge(f.read(), config)

sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(
  log_device_placement=False,
  allow_soft_placement = True
)

sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)

def load_model():

  # Loading model that will be used.
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, 
      [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],config.model_path)

  graph = tf.get_default_graph()
  input_image = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input_image:0')
  ....
  ....
  params = some parameters
  return params

def get_data(im,ftype,params):
  try:
    img = tf.read_file(im)
    image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  except Exception as e:
    print ("## Got Exception while reading: ", e)
    return None

  im = sess.run(image_tf)
  pred = sess.run(....)
  return pred

params = load_model(sess)

@app.route("/data", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    url = request.args.get('path')
    print ("##","recieved")
    if not path:
        abort(400)

    pred = get_data(image,"url",params)
    return pred

if __name__ == "__main__":

  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8011,use_reloader=False)
```

Finally I run the app using:

```
`uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8011 --wsgi-file api.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --callable app --lazy --lazy-apps`
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that uwsgi forks processes to run multiple "copies" of your app.

However, you instantiate your graph outside of that context. Your callable is `app` so the model should be instantiated in it.
You can use the `before_first_request` callback to load your model.

This blog post could be handy to understand how to set it up:
https://networklore.com/start-task-with-flask/

Relevant flask documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you solved your problem yet? I have had similar issues and with Keras I can fix the issue by using Theano instead of Tensorflow.

I had to add the code below to my script and use `KERAS_BACKEND=theano python myprogram.py` to run the program on a Linux OS.

`import theano
theano.config.optimizer="None"`

See this stackoverflow post:

[Theano error deep learning python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51655266/theano-error-deep-learning-python/51657755?noredirect=1#comment90283924_51657755)